# Shading between parametric equations using two functions

Tags: plotting, syntax

I have a two functions:

```
f[α_, γ_,  u_] := Cosh[u]*Sqrt[1 - [([Sin[α] Sinh[u]]^2)]/[Sqrt[1- γ]*Cosh[u] + Cos[α]]^2];
b[α_, γ_, u_] := -1*[[[Sinh[u]]^2*Sin[α]]/[Sqrt[[1- γ]] Cosh[u] + Cos[α]];
```

and now I want to do ParametricPlot as

```
ParametricPlot[f[8 π/5, 0.15, u], b[8 π/5, 0.15, u], {u, -2, 2}]
```

I am trying to plot between function `f` and `b`, but not getting any plot.

Comment: First, you need to add brackets in `ParametricPlot`.

Answer (score 4):

After fixing the syntax errors in your code:

```
f[α_, γ_, u_] := Cosh[u] Sqrt[1 - (Sin[α] Sinh[u])^2]/(Sqrt[1 - γ] Cosh[u] + Cos[α])^2;
b[α_, γ_, u_] := -Sinh[u]^2*Sin[α]/(Sqrt[1 - γ] Cosh[u] +  Cos[α]);
ParametricPlot[{f[8*π/5, 0.15, u], b[8*π/5, 0.15, u]}, {u, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

By  ***plot between function f and b*** you probably mean something like

```
Plot[{f[8 π/5, 0.15, u], b[8 π/5, 0.15, u]}, {u, -2, 2}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Yellow, Red}}}]
```

[image]